how does tomcat start?
I installed tomcat from the default Ubuntu 20.04 packages, but I cannot find out how to start it. dpkg -L tomcat9 gives me no /etc/init.d script. There is only /usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-start.sh and when I call this, I
get/usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-start.sh: 25: exec: /bin/catalina.sh: not found

How do I start tomcat9 when installed from Ubuntu?

Have you try with systemctl? By default this is the way to start daemons in Ubuntu 20.

If I install tomcat9 on ubuntu 23.04 ("Lunar Lobster"), the package provides /lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service:
root@ubuntu:~# dpkg -L tomcat9 | grep systemd
/lib/systemd
/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service

Starting the service works as expected:
systemctl start tomcat9.service

Ubuntu adopted systemd back in 2015, and legacy /etc/init.d scripts have been deprecated since then.
